# Remove * (significance) from ggpairs

Tags: r

In recent version of `GGally::ggpair`s correlation values are shown with *'s as seen in the figure below. I'd like to remove the *s and keep the correlation values.

I had a look at the ggpairs code but it isn't obvious to me.

```
GGally::ggpairs(data = iris[, 1:4])
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the correlation values altogether or keep them but just remove the * that flags significant correlations?

Comment: Just remove the *s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(GGally)

GGally::ggpairs(data = iris[, 1:4], 
                upper = list(continuous = GGally::wrap(ggally_cor, stars = F)))
```

[image]

According to the documentation:

> If a specific function needs its parameters set, wrap(fn, param1 = val1, param2 = val2) the function with its parameters.

`stars` is a function argument to `GGally::ggally_cor`:

> logical value which determines if the significance stars should be displayed. Given the cor.test p-values...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.